How to send MIME message using Graph SDK V5 (.NET)
Currently, I'm working on sending reserved mail system using graph sdk.
I'm trying to send saved .eml file(Mimecontent) using graph sdk (v5).
I found some way on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http but it only show way for http.
Therefore, I'm using MIMEKIT library and reconstruct the email and send but I don't think this is a best way to do it.
byte[] newbuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(newbuffer)) {
    var mimeMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.Load(memoryStream);
    var message = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Message
    {
        Subject = mimeMessage.Subject,
        Body = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = mimeMessage.HtmlBody != null ? Microsoft.Graph.Models.BodyType.Html : Microsoft.Graph.Models.BodyType.Text,
            Content = mimeMessage.HtmlBody ?? mimeMessage.TextBody
        },
        ToRecipients = mimeMessage.To.Mailboxes.Select(mailbox => new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress { Address = mailbox.Address }
        }).ToList()
    };
    var draftMessage = await gsc.Users[userinfo.UserPrincipalName].Messages.PostAsync(message);
    foreach (var attachment in mimeMessage.Attachments.OfType<MimeKit.MimePart>())
    {
        var attachmentStream = new MemoryStream();
        attachment.Content.DecodeTo(attachmentStream);
        byte[] fileBytes = attachmentStream.ToArray(); 
        attachmentStream.Dispose(); 
        var fileAttachment = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.FileAttachment
        {
            OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            ContentBytes = fileBytes,
            ContentType = attachment.ContentType.MimeType,
            Name = attachment.FileName
        };
        await gsc.Users[userinfo.UserPrincipalName].Messages[draftMessage.Id].Attachments.PostAsync(fileAttachment);
    }
    await gsc.Users[userinfo.UserPrincipalName].Messages[draftMessage.Id].Send.PostAsync();
}

I'm wondering I may use ToPostRequestInformation for more simple way? Or anyone know the other way? please help me

If your mail message inclusive attachements is bigger then 2 MB, this is the only way to send it. Otherwise you could use graphClient.Users["senderUserId"].SendMail.PostAsync(message), to make it in one go.

Something like this should work
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var base64content = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
var ri = graphClient.Users["xxx"].SendMail.ToPostRequestInformation(new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody());
ri.Headers.Clear();// replace the json content header
ri.SetStreamContent(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64content)), "text/plain");
var result = await graphClient.RequestAdapter.SendAsync<Message>(ri, Message.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue);

